# How do I pass in the random int into my switch

Tags: java, random, switch-statement

I just can't figure out why I'm getting a NullPointerException. The program gets to the first case and says `i` is not pointing to anything.

```
public String computerChoice()
{   
    int i = ran.nextInt(4);
    String str;
    switch (i){
    case 1:  
        str = "paper";
    case 2: 
        str = "rock";
    case 3: 
        str = "scissors";
    default:
        str = "not valid";   
    }
    return str;
}
```

Comment: What line raises it ? Can you share a reproducible code : include `ran` instanciation/definition

Comment: Assumption: `ran` is `null`. Solution: Change `int i = ran.nextInt(4);` to `int i = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(4);` it should probably be `int i = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(4) + 1;`

Comment: You need to add the `break;` statement in each `case` block otherwise you get fall-through right to `default`. Also change the `int i = rnd.nextInt(4);` to `int i = rnd.nextInt(3) + 1;` as already suggested. Use `3` instead of `4` then you don't need to worry about default, or...is that a requirement in the game?. I like @Alex's array suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Therre are several issues in your code:

1. It does not show that the `Random` instance `ran` is initialized and this should be the root cause of `NullPointerException`
2. `switch` statement is written *without* `break` or `return`, therefore, `"not valid"` would be always returned after fixing the NPE
3. Only *three valid* options should be generated and used in this rock-scissors-stone generator.

Possible fixes:

1. Use Java 12 `switch` expression syntax:

```java
public String computerChoice() {   
    return switch (new Random().nextInt(3)) {  // values in range [0..2]
        case 0 -> "paper";
        case 1 -> "rock";
        default -> "scissors"; // the only remaining value 2 should be default
    }
}
```

2. Use `return` in older `switch` statement:

```java
public String computerChoice() {   
    switch (new Random().nextInt(3)) {  // values in range [0..2]
        case 0: return "paper";
        case 1: return "rock";
        default: return "scissors";
    }
}
```

3. Create and use an array of possible values without any `switch` at all to reduce the code complexity:

```java
private static final String PRS = {"paper", "rock", "scissors"};

public String computerChoice() {   
    return PRS[new Random().nextInt(PRS.length)];
}
```